# Xcode: dragging from ViewController Icon

Tags: xcode

In Xcode,

1. what does it mean to drag from the orange ViewController icon to lets say a Label.
2. how is this different from dragging a line from the Label to the interface to setup an outlet?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use the assistent editor (interface builder and header file) then one way dragging is making an outlet, and the other way is to make an action (for example to make a UIButton IBAction method).

When you use the assistent editor you can just drag from the UI object to the header file and choose to make an outlet or an action:

[image]

Comment: Then why is that when i dragged from view controller to the label to create an outlet, it doesn't create a line of code in the header file as if I dragged the label to the header file to create the outlet?

Comment: When you drag from the view controller (like you do in your picture) you want to bind the connection, not create it. You have first create the IBOutlet manually in the header file. The nice thing of the assistant editor is that xcode creates the outlet for you (and if you don't user ARC, he even create the release in the dealloc). I hope it makes more clear.